# C# вывод системы векторов

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, возникло затруднение в следующем: как вывести в форму заданную систему векторов? Буду благодарен за помощь

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace c_system
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public struct TupleComp //компонента кортежа
    {
        public int var; //номер переменной
        public uint value; //значения

        public static TupleComp Set(int avar,uint avalue)  //что такое set? //почему и public и static?
        {
            TupleComp result;
            result.var = avar;
            result.value = avalue;
            return result;
        }

        public TupleComp(int avar, uint avalue)
        {
            var = avar;
            value = avalue;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] all_variables = new int[] { 3, 2, 4 }; //задаю количества значений у используемых переменных x1, x2, x3;
        TupleComp[] tuple1 = new TupleComp[] { TupleComp.Set(0, 1), TupleComp.Set(2, 3) }; //(x1,1)(x3,1+x3,2) 
        TupleComp[] tuple2 = new TupleComp[] { TupleComp.Set(1, 2), TupleComp.Set(2, 1<<1 | 1<<3) }; //(x2,2)(x3,2+x3,4) 
        TupleComp[][] system = new TupleComp[][] { tuple1, tuple2 };   //С-система

        public String PrintTupleComp(int var, uint value)
    {
        //result = val1 + val2 + ... + valN
    }

    public String PrintTuple(TupleComp[] tuple)
    {
        //result = comp1 * comp2 + ... + compN
    }

    public String PrintSystem(TupleComp[][] system)
    {
        //result = tuple1 + tuple2 + ... + tupleN
    }



    }


            private void system_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

Comment: А в каком виде вы хотите, чтобы было выведено?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.